# DateTime to Datetime2

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have started to use entity framework and after doing research i have found that Entity Framework only accepts the DateTime format DateTime2.

What is the best way to convert a DateTime picker to the format of Datetime2

I currently do the following

```
string strCastFrom = this.dtCastFrom.Value.Year.ToString("0000") + "-" + this.dtCastFrom.Value.Month.ToString("00") + "-" + this.dtCastFrom.Value.Day.ToString("00") + "T00:00:00";
```

Is therea better way to convert datetime to DateTime2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't perform *any* string conversions. Just use

```
DateTime value = dtCastFrom.Value;
```

Let the Entity Framework itself take care of getting the data to the database. You don't *want* a string representation, and there's no reason to go *via* a string representation. This isn't just the case for EF, it's a general principle.

Comment: When i do this i get a error."The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Comment: @Inkey: At what point? What are you doing when the error occurs - fetching, inserting, something else? What is the value? What does your SQL schema look like? You really haven't given us enough information here.

Comment: it happens there i do the .SaveChanges();

Comment: @Inkey: So that's answered *one* of my questions - what about the other two? (I'm not going to have time to keep asking questions again and again, I'm afraid. I'm trying to help you, but you really need to think about what information would be useful. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list)

Comment: your answer helped me with the question i asked i have gone off track a little thanks for your help.